# How to I modify or remove existing summary_fields when extending an Object in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm extending the Member object which has the following summary_fields (that appear in the Security section of the CMS).

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'FirstName' => 'First Name',
    'Surname' => 'Last Name',
    'Email' => 'Email',
);
```

How would I remove 'FirstName' and 'Surname' and replace them with a custom field from the data extension: 'Full Name'?

How would I change 'Email' to read 'Email Address'?

I know how to add summary_fields via a data extension but I don't know how to remove or change them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a `DataObject` has set a `$summary_fields` we cannot remove fields from this through an extension. The extension's `$summary_fields` is merged with the original `$summary_fields`.

To stop the merging of `$summary_fields` we need to override the DataObject's `updateSummaryFields()` function. Instead we will make the `updateSummaryFields()` function return just the extension's `$summary_fields`.

```php
class MemberExtension extends DataExtension {

    private static $summary_fields = array( 
        'FullName' => 'Full Name', 
        'EmailAddress' => 'Email Address'
    );

    private static $casting = array(
        'FullName' => 'Text', 
        'EmailAddress' => 'Text'
    );


    public function updateSummaryFields(&$fields) {
        $fields = Config::inst()->get($this->class, 'summary_fields');
    }

    public function getFullName() {
        return $this->owner->FirstName . ' ' . $this->owner->Surname; 
    }

    public function getEmailAddress() {
        return $this->owner->Email; 
    }
}
```

It also seems we cannot change the field label of an existing field, like `Email`. What we can do instead is cast a new field `EmailAddress` that will return the content of `Email`. Now we can set the label that we want.

Comment: Thank you @3dgoo Something worth noting for anyone who looks at this. It seems like I have to recast any Object fields I want to add to $summary_fields if I use the updateSummaryFields over-write.

For example: adding FirstName to $summaryfields results in a blank field. But adding ShowFirstName and setting getShowFirstName: return $this->owner->FirstName; works.

Comment: That's really interesting @Tama. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: Thanks for this, I kept adding more to member but could never overwrite using $summary_fields.

Comment: @BaronGrivet, if you're using multiple properties of the owner, rather than creating many methods to return `$this->owner->Property`, make a single method that returns `$this->owner` instead, then, in your `$summary_fields`, you can use dot notation to access the properties;

`'Owner.FirstName' => 'First Name'` and so on...